# Second Element as Pivot in Quicksort

Tags: algorithm, pivot, quicksort

I have an assignment that involves the Quicksort algorithm. I have read it severally from different texts and sites like GeeksforGeeks, FCC, JavaPoint, etc. I understand the algorithm, and I understand the sample codes.

The problem I am facing is that the lecturer requires that the pivot is the second element, `arr[1]`.

Here is the code I wrote, for partitioning:

```py
arr = [34, 8, 3, 4, 5, 67, 43]

pivot = arr[1]
j = 0
for i in range(len(arr)):
    if arr[i] >= pivot:
        j = i
    if arr[i] < pivot and i > 1:
        arr[i], arr[j] = arr[j], arr[i]

print(arr)

[What I got]: [34, 8, 3, 4, 5, 67, 43]

[Expected}: [4, 3, 5, 8, 67, 34, 43]
```

I understand that that chunk of code should be wrapped in a partition function, and I will recursively sort the left and right parts.

So, can someone help me look into it?

Comment: If the pivot is required to be arr[1], I don't see why it can't be swapped with the first or last element if using Lomuto partition scheme, or with the middle element if using Hoare partition scheme, before doing each actual partition step.

Comment: did the lecturer provide a pseudo algorithm or a definition of the partitioning ? How did you get the expected result ? The order of `3,4,5` -> `4,3,5` seems odd to me.

Comment: It is clear why your algorithm is wrong, but it is not clear why the expected output should have that order. Please clarify.

Comment: The order of the elements to the left and right of 8 does not matter, it may be sorted or not in the first run. Through recursion, I can sort both sides of the array.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you tried to implement the Lomuto partition scheme, but there are some issues with it:

1. `j = i` is not right. It sets `j` to the *most recent* entry you have found that is not less than the pivot. But thereby you might skip over a previous entry that was also in that situation, and which was not swapped yet. So that previous one is now forever assigned to the left partition, while it should end up in the right partition. Instead, `j` should point to the *first* entry you have found that is not less than the pivot, or in other words, it should mark the start of the right partition, and should therefore only increment with steps of 1.
2. After the loop has ended, your code does not ensure that the pivot value is placed between the two resulting partitions. The Lomuto partition scheme does this so that the caller can exclude this index from the two partitions that will be the subject of recursive calls.

Here is a corrected version using the Lomuto partition scheme:

```py
def partition(arr, lo, hi):
    pivot = arr[lo + 1]  # The second value in the current partition
    # Swap the pivot out of the way (to the far right)
    arr[hi], arr[lo + 1] = pivot, arr[hi]
    for i in range(lo, hi):  # Iterate the range, excluding the pivot
        if arr[i] <= pivot: 
            arr[i], arr[lo] = arr[lo], arr[i]
            lo += 1  # Increase the index where the righthand partition starts
    # Move the pivot value (from the right) to the correct pivot index
    arr[hi], arr[lo] = arr[lo], arr[hi]
    return lo  # Return the pivot index
```

Call as:

```py
arr = [34, 8, 3, 4, 5, 67, 43]
partition(arr, 0, len(arr) - 1)
```

Comment: With your approach of moving the second element to the far right, I got an insight, and I have the following code that works. ```def quicksort(arr):
    
    # The pivot is always the second element
    pivot = arr[1]
    
    # Let's first move the pivot to the far right in the array
    arr[-1], arr[1] = pivot, arr[-1]
    
    j = -1
    
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        if arr[i] > arr[-1]:
            i += 1
        else:
            j += 1
            arr[i], arr[j] = arr[j], arr[i]
    
    return j
    
print(quicksort([11, 5, 23, 45, 2, 3, 4]))````

Comment: Is it possible not to move the pivot to the far right at all?

Comment: I couldn't read that code (code doesn't render well in comments), but incrementing the loop variable `i` is useless, and without `lo`, `hi` you cannot generalise this to implement quicksort. By making one more iteration you do move the pivot in place, but you make one more comparison. Yes there are hundreds of ways to implement quicksort. For instance Hoare's scheme. Or with Lomuto you can move the element to the left. If you don't initially move it you need to realise that it will probably still move, and you need more code. Have a go at it, and if it doesn't work, ask a question about it.